# How to get the landing url using Javascript

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, session-cookies

The goal is to get the first URL that the users are landing on my site and keep that information until the page is closed.

Could you suggest to me a code that accomplishes this task by using Javascript? I'm working on a GTM tag and this would be of great help.

Comment: Store the URL in session storage.

Comment: `sessionStorage.landing = sessionStorage.landing || location.href;` then, `sessionStorage.landing` will always be your landing page for that domain on that tab.